# VC dimension of vector spaces

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, discrete-geometry, hypergraph

Does the collection of all subspaces of a fixed finite-dimensional vector space have bounded [VC dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapnik%E2%80%93Chervonenkis_dimension)?

Could someone please provide references for this question?

Comment: Could you please be more precise about the particular set system or lattice whose VC dimension you are considering? Are you thinking of the subspaces of some fixed (finite-dimensional) vector space?

Comment: @YemonChoi  Yes, I meant the subspaces of some fixed (finite-dimensional) vector space.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the VC dimension is at most the dimension $d$.  To see this consider a set $X$ of size more than $d$ and pick a basis $B$ for $X$.  If a subspace contains $B$, then it must also contain $X$.  Thus, there is no subspace $S$ such that $S \cap X=B$.

Comment: @TonyHuynh: What is d?

Comment: @Ken $d$ is the dimension of the finite-dimensional vector space.

Comment: For the uninitiated: VC stands for [Vapnik-Chervonenkis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapnik%E2%80%93Chervonenkis_dimension)

Comment: The question is ill-posed, voting to close. VC dimension applies to a *set system*, i.e., a ground set and a collection of its subsets. As stated, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 7):

I will turn my comment above into a self-contained answer. Given a hypergraph $H=(V,E)$ and $X \subseteq V$, we say that $X$ is *shattered* if for all $X' \subseteq X$, there exists $e \in E$ such that $e \cap X=X'$.  The *VC dimension* of $H$ is the size of a largest shattered set.  Given a finite dimensional vector space $\mathbb V$, let $H$ be the hypergraph with vertex set $\mathbb V$ and whose edges are the subspaces of $\mathbb V$.  I claim that the VC dimension of $H$ is $d$, where $d$ is the dimension of $\mathbb V$.  To see this, let $B$ be a basis of $\mathbb V$.  For every subset $A$ of $B$, let $S_A$ be the subspace generated by $A$.  Then $S_A \cap B=A$, and so $B$ is a shattered set of size $d$.  Thus, the VC dimension of $H$ is at least $d$. On the other hand if $X$ is a set of size more than $d$ and $X' \subseteq X$ is a basis for the subspace generated by $X$, then every subspace which contains $X'$ also contains $X$.  Therefore, there is no subspace $S$ such that $S \cap X=X'$, and so $X$ is not a shattered set.

Comment: Perhaps this is why VC dimension is called... dimension

Comment: I think you forgot to specify that $X'\subseteq X$ (so it's not just any basis, but one obtained by throwing away some elements of $X$).

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thanks, that got accidentally deleted while editing.